# Getting NaN as a result when using all number types in an equation - Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting `NaN` (not a number) as a result for `totalPotential` and `ratings`, here is the code:

```
for (let x in item.rating) {
   if(typeof x == 'string') {
     console.log("intparsed88888888");
     item.rating[x] = parseInt(x);
   }
}    

console.log(typeof item.rating.one + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(\n" +
            typeof item.rating.two + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(\n"+
            typeof item.rating.three + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(\n"+
            typeof item.rating.four + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(\n"+
            typeof item.rating.five + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(fivefive\n");

totalPotential = item.rating.one * 5 + item.rating.two * 5 + item.rating.three * 5 + item.rating.four * 5 + item.rating.five * 5;
ratings = item.rating.one + item.rating.two * 2 + item.rating.three * 3 + item.rating.four * 4 + item.rating.five *5;
```

The `console.log` output shows that all of the variables are numbers (a lot of them are zeros...but that shouldn't mess up anything). Why do I get `NaN` for `totalPotentials` and `ratings` when all of the variables involved are numbers?

**UPDATE**
I output the `item.rating` objects and they are all `NaN` so something is going wrong in the `for` loop where I am changing them from a string to a number. I added that part above at the top of the code.

Comment: `typeof NaN === "number"`

Comment: why could i be getting it as a result? all of the variables are numbers 0 ->

Comment: Did you log the numbers themselves? Please include a complete example.

Comment: Why don't you post your `item.rating` object.

Comment: please run console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); to provide an example of the item

Comment: i just noticed...all of the item.rating objects are NaN so something is wrong with when I am turning it into a number...ill update my code

Comment: Yeah, `parseInt` can’t parse “five” into 5.

Comment: yah thats not what im trying to do...i need to get the value of the property that is in the loop `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt( x )` is trying to read a leading sign followed by a sequence of digits from a provided value optionally converted to string first. If provided value or its string representation doesn't meet this expectation the result returned by `parseInt( x )` is `NaN`, "not a number" ... This is still a number, but one with no actual value, just the type of being a number.

In addition your iteration might suffer from enumerating *derived* properties of `item.ratings` unintentionally.

According to your console.log you probably want sth. like this:

```
for ( let x in item.ratings ) {
  if ( typeof item.ratings[x] === "string" ) {
    item.ratings[x] = parseInt( item.ratings[x] );
  }
}
```

Still using `for .. in`-loop usually requires additional care due to object *inheritance* as mentioned before:

```
for ( let x in item.ratings ) {
  if ( item.ratings.hasOwnProperty( x ) && typeof item.ratings[x] === "string" ) {
    item.ratings[x] = parseInt( item.ratings[x] );
  }
}
```

Comment: *“for .. in is enumerating all properties of item.rating, which includes item.rating.length in case of an array”* `length` is not an enumerable property, but `item.ratings` doesn’t seem to be an array anyway.

Comment: @Ryan You are basically right, though I remember having related issues with older browsers such as Safari 5.1 on Windows enumerating over an array's length, too. Nonetheless it is always safer to use `hasOwnProperty()` when traversing properties of object using `for .. in`.

Comment: item.rating is an `object` not an array, which is why I am using `for...in`

Comment: I finally edited the answer to skip the array-related issue. Nonetheless, don't iterate w/o checking every property to be owned by object itself unless you know what you are doing.